# How ng-include builds url in Angular 1.5?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-ng-include

Am using Angular1.5 with asp.net mvc.

By default when my application loads it points to http://domainname/components/Webui/Home/Instructions

Home - controller,
Instructions - Action

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {       

        public ActionResult Instructions()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

above url returns an html

which contains below

```
<div>
<div ng-include src="app/Layout/shell/Shell.html" class="height100">

</div>
</div>
```

But it is not able to download the shell.html.
it is generating the wrong url as below

http://domainname/components/Webui/Home/app/layout/shell/Shell.html

**In the above url why Home is coming ?**

My folder structure is

```
app
  layout
     shell
        Shell.html
Controllers
Views
  Home
     Index.cshtml
     Instructions.cshtm
```

Please correct me if anything is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a relative path from index. Append forward slash to path to traverse from project root:

```
ng-include src="/app/Layout/shell/Shell.html
```

Comment: after trying that url was like this`http://domainname/components/app/layout/shell/Shell.html`